After migrating to Angular 18 with the new build system I got an error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bindingStartIndex')
I have updated a project that I use as a library for my application from angular 17 to angular 18, and I have updated all the packages as usual. I have also accepted the migration to the new build system.
npm i typescript@5.5.4
ng update @angular/core@18 ng update @angular/cli@18 
ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@18 ng update @angular/material@18

and when I run the library I get this error in the browser console:
main.ts:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bindingStartIndex')
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:23501:53)
    at AppComponent2_Template (template.html:1:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11788:5)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12950:7)
    at renderComponent (core.mjs:12896:3)
    at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:12996:5)
    at renderView (core.mjs:12978:7)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:16260:9)
    at _ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.mjs:31811:38)
    at core.mjs:33216:56

In my package.json I have added a package locally that is the component that should be rendered, I don't know if that could be the problem and that something has changed the way to import packages locally.
"@mylib/dashboards": "file:./MyLib.Dashboards/dist/dashboards/mylib-dashboards-18.0.0.tgz"

Since in the tsconfig.json I had already added the path of the angular libraries, which is the solution I have seen people giving to this problem
“paths": {
  “@angular/*": [
    “node_modules/@angular/*”
  ],

I also tried to add in the angular.json the preserveSymlinks section, but nothing changed.
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
             "preserveSymlinks": true,

However if I remove this path from “@angular/*” I get no error but the mocks data with which I test the library does not load. I create this mocks data with InMemoryDataService which implements InMemoryDbService creating a database.
package.json:
{
  "name": "widgets-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "jest --coverage --verbose --silent",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build_prod": "ng build widgets --configuration production",
    "pack": "cd dist/widgets && npm pack",
    "package": "npm run build_prod && npm run pack",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^18.2.7",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^18.0.1",
    "@mylib/dashboards": "file:../MyLib.Dashboards/dist/dashboards/mylib-dashboards-18.0.0.tgz",
    "@mylib/layout": "^18.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-pivotview": "^27.1.48",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.18.0",
    "echarts": "^5.4.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-dynamic-component": "^10.7.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^6.0.4",
    "ngx-echarts": "^18.0.0",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^18.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^18.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.2.7",
    "@ngneat/spectator": "^19.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.13",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint": "^9.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-auto-spies": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^14.2.4",
    "jest-sonar": "^0.2.16",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.13.1",
    "ng-packagr": "^18.2.1",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "~5.5.4"
  }
}


please share a sample import of how you are using the library  in your application, it should not be like projects/my-component/src/public-api also try removing “paths": {   “@angular/*": [     “node_modules/@angular/*”   ], and checking with a fresh install after deleting the .angular  folder

Can you share your package.json folder? I also had a similar problem during the upgrade but it was a versioning issue

@Jason Added package.json

Just a quick question is it expected to not have @angular/cli in your package.json dependencies? That might be the issue

@NarenMurali import {  } from '@mylib/dashboards';

@Jason @angular/cli I have it in devDependencies, even so I have moved it and it still gives me the error.

@NarenMurali if I remove angular path it works, but it doesn't show the mock data I use to test the library using angular-in-memory-web-api. I don't know if this affects the mock data or if it is another problem.

@Laura removing this “@angular/*": [     “node_modules/@angular/*”  should not affect your  angular-in-memory-web-api so it's some other issue.

Yes, you are right. It seems that a request is failing in the service of @mylib/dashboards, as it does not print the value.
this._http.get<Dashboard[]>(url, httpOptions)
.pipe(
tap(d => {
console.log(d);
}),
catchError()
);
Even though in the libreary app itself it does it correctly.

You can try removing the  angular line from the paths array, this might solve the problem.
Before:
“paths": {
  “@angular/*": [
    “node_modules/@angular/*”
  ],

After:
“paths": {},

